# How can I call oracle DB stored procedures which having multiple refcursors using EF6 Code first - Existing DB Approach?

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, oracle12c

I am new to Entity framework. I am having existing oracle db with several stored procedures which having multiple ref cursors. Now I am trying to access those stored procedures by using EF6 code first approach. How can i do this please help me.

For example I am having Country.cs as below:

```
public partial class Country
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ForeignName { get; set; }
    public string StateFlag { get; set; }
    public string ZipCodeFlag { get; set; }
    public string EUFlag { get; set; }
    public string CrossBookingFlag { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> PurgeYear { get; set; }
}
```

and I am having Oracle stored procedure "ibp_country_mstr_getlist" like below:

```
procedure ibp_country_mstr_getlist
      (       
       p_country_id   in     number,           
       p_cntry_getlist out   SYS_REFCURSOR
       )as begin
  open   p_cntry_getlist  for
  select /*+index(ibt_country_master country_mas_status_idx)*/country_pid,country_code,country_name,country_fname
 from     ibt_country_master
where     country_pid=p_country_id
and       country_status in ('A','D'); end;
```

How can I access this stored procedure using ef6 code first for existing db and assign the returning result set to List?

Answer (score 0):

Use telerik data access it work for me.
first download telerik and map your db using `Telerik Data Access Domain Model`then in `Model Schema Explorer` find your stored procedure and right click on the `stored procedure` then `create domain method` and click on `Retrieve Result Shape` and create complex type

```
using (EntitiesModel1 entitiesModel1 = new EntitiesModel1())
{
    var z = entitiesModel1.GETBINDEDSUBSCRIPTIONSP("some text");
    Console.WriteLine(z.Count());
}
```

you will get an exception like this: `Unable to cast object of type Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' to type Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.`
go to stored procedure definition and change `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter` to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter` and specify parameter direction for each parameter.
don't forget to add `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` as reference to your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately i cant use telerik data access, i have to use EF ORM only. What is the procedure to do this using EF code first approach